VBA - Combo Box as a search field and Form updater
I have a form with a recordsource
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE BRANCHES ='OPEN'

This form has several textfields and combo boxes which are bound.
I have one combo box cboName bound to the Form, which I would like to use as a search field, in the sense that if I type a few letters in the combo box, then my selection from the combo box should only have the names which are possible from the letter typed. Then selecting one of the choices should give me an update to the form. So I thought this procedure would make sense in the cbo_Afterupdate
Private Sub cboName_AfterUpdate()


Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False

If Len(Me.cboName.Value) > 0 Then
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Name FROM TABLE_A WHERE Name Like '*" & Me.cboName.Value & "*'"
    Me.cboName.Requery
Else
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT Name FROM TABLE_A "
    Me.cboName.Requery
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cboName.Value) Then
    Me.Filter = "Name = '" & Me.cboName.Value & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If


End Sub

Now, I get an error 3464(data conflict) on the line Me.FilterOn = True I noticed that with f5 it continues, but the form is not filled, what am I missing?
Thanks in advance

Remove the Requery calls and check the value of Me.Filter.

the Me.Filter has what I would expect "Name = 'Smith'"...Does that maybe not work with the recourdsource of the form?

The combobox must be unbound.

thanks that did it. How can I show my appreciation here?

Great! I wrote an answer you can mark.

The combobox must be unbound - or you will attempt to update and filter the form in one go, which you can't.
